# Why do i get NumberFormatException when converting from Hex to decimal, and how can i prevent it? - Java

Tags: java, hex, decimal

This is my method for converting a String Hex to a decimal:

```
private int fromHexToPercent(String hex){
    int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    return decimal;
}
```

When i call it on these values: `#ffe87e, #ffc6bb, #528b7a, #9b81ff, #7d6a32, #000c40` among others I get the following exception on this line:

```
   int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

Error:

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
```

Here is my method for converting from rgb to hex, i got a feeling that Java has å problem with  this line: hex = "0" + hex;. But it needs to be there to get the hex-code right.

```
    public static String toHex(int r, int g, int b) {
return "#" + toBrowserHexValue(r) + toBrowserHexValue(g) +  toBrowserHexValue(b);
}

private static String toHexValue(int number) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(number & 0xff);
    while (hex.length() < 2) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Really hope somebody can see a solution to this problem =)

Comment: Because those aren't valid hexadecimal? There's no `#` in a hexadecimal number, and it's telling you that.

Comment: Why is there a '#' character at the start of your hex values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only valid hex digits are 0-9 and a-f (or A-F). `#` is not a valid hex digit.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `#` from the hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead do it with numbers that do not start with unknown characters. such as `#` and `0x`.